# Swap specific text in string

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I need to write a function *swapLetters* that receives two strings. The function transforms the string received as the first parameter by replacing the first character from the string that is passed as the second parameter with the last character from the same string, the second with the previous one, etc. to the middle of the string. If the second parameter contains an odd number of characters, nothing needs to be done with the character in the middle. If one of the parameters is an empty string, the function does not need to do anything.

For example:

```
char text[9]="dobar dan", letters[5]="abcde";
```

OUTPUT:

```
After transformation text is: 'doder den'
```

Explanation: first character in the string *letters* is "a", and in the string *text*, character "a" is replaced by the last character of string *letters*, which is "e". The second charater from string *letters* is "b", and in the string *text*, charater "b" is replaced by the penultimate character of string *letters*, which is "d", while with the letter "c "nothing has been done because it is in the middle of the string *letters* and there the function stops.

The function should return the cursor to the beginning of a text string for easier chain calling.

*Note: Auxiliary strings are not allowed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *swapLetters(char *s1, char *s2) {
  int lenght1 = 0, lenght2 = 0;
  char *q1 = s1, *q2 = s2;
  while (*q1 != '\0') {
    lenght1++;
    q1++;
  }
  while (*q2 != '\0') {
    lenght2++;
    q2++;
  }
  return s1;
}

int main() {
  char text[9] = "dobar dan", letters[5] = "abcde";
  swapLetters(text, letters);
  printf("After transformation text is: '%s'\n", text);
  return 0;
}
```

Could you help me with this task? Strings are new to me.

Comment: You are testing for a `'\0'` terminator, but the array lengths are too short, and there aren't any. Try `letters[] = "abcde"` etc., and allow the compiler to auto-size the arrays and add the terminators.

Comment: (Answering "can I use `strlen`?") Not as you have them, because `strlen` (and most string functions) relies on the string being terminated. That's how it finds the length (as you do). Don't specifiy the array size: let the compiler do it.

Comment: Please don't make rolling corrections to the posted code: you end up destroying the question by posting bug-free code.

Comment: on my compiler (msvc) this doesn't even compile because of `char text[9] = "dobar dan"`, you must have been at least getting warnings, dont ignore warnings

Comment: @pm100: That line is perfectly valid code. It just does not do what the OP intended; it *should* compile just fine.

Comment: @DevSolar yes i was compiling as c++. I am surprised its not even a warning at -pedantic level

Comment: @pm100 In my VS-2019, MSVC gives: *warning C4295: 'letters': array is too small to include a terminating null character* (and similarly for `text`).

Comment: @AdrianMole yup i see that now, I ran the code through gcc and it was silent tho.

Comment: @pm100: It is explicitly allowed. 6.7.4 Initialization (14), emphasis mine: "Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
terminating null character *if there is room or if the array is of unknown size*) initialize the
elements of the array."

Comment: @DevSolar yup, but lots of things are allowed that still generate warnings.

Comment: @pm100: Well, the point here is that it is valid to initialize a `char[]` with something that is not, strictly speaking, a C string. Embedded `'\0'` are likewise allowed. Or, to put it differently -- all C strings are a char array, but not all char arrays are a C string. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed, you are not providing enough space for your strings to have `'\0'` terminator.

You need to change to:

```
char text[10] = "dobar dan"; 
char letters[6] = "abcde";
```

But also, your function `swapLetters` is not swapping any characters:

A correct function would have been:

```
char *swapLetters(char *s1, char *s2) {
  int length2 = 0;

  char *q1 = s1, *q2 = s2;

  while (*q2 != '\0') {
    length2++;
    q2++;
  }

  while (*q1 != '\0') {
    // find the char in striong 'letters'
    for(int i=0; i<length2/2; i++){
        if(*q1 == s2[i]){
            *q1 = s2[length2-i-1];
        }
    }
    q1++;
  }
  
  return s1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this issue using two *nested* loops. The outer loop should use two pointers to the characters in the `s2` string that should be checked-for and changed-to, respectively; the inner loop should (repeatedly) run through the `s1` string, looking for occurrences of the target character, and change that if found.

You haven't specified what to do if there is any "overlap" between the character(s) to change and those that should be substituted but, in the code below, I have included an array of 'flags' to prevent multiple substitutions, in such cases. If you *don't* want this behaviour, or if the values of the `s2` string simply won't allow it, then you can remove all references to the `done` array.

I have included comments that explain (I hope) what the code does, and the two lines commented out with the `///` triple-slash can be un-commented if you want to watch what the function does "on the fly".

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* swapLetters(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    // A quick sanity check ...
    if (!strlen(s1) || !strlen(s2)) return s1; // Zero-length strings!

    // First, let's get pointers to the first/last characters of s2...
    char* sub_beg = s2;
    char* sub_end = s2 + strlen(s2) - 1;

    size_t src_len = strlen(s1); // So we don't have to keep calling "strlen"

    // Now, we need an array to keep track of characters we've ALREADY changed...
    int* done = calloc(src_len, sizeof(int)); // calloc set all elements to ZERO
    if (!done) {
        puts("Cannot allocate workspace!");
        return s1;
    }

    // Outer loop: run until beginning and end meet or cross over...
    while (sub_beg < sub_end) {
    /// printf("Checking for %c change to %c ... \n", *sub_beg, *sub_end);
        // Inner loop: run through the source and change if found...
        for (size_t i = 0; i < src_len; ++i) {
            if (s1[i] == *sub_beg && !done[i]) {
            /// printf("Swapping %c for %c ... \n", s1[i], *sub_end);
                s1[i] = *sub_end; // Make change
                done[i] = 1;     // Flag that we've changed it
            }
        }
        ++sub_beg; // Increment beginning
        --sub_end; // Decrement end
    }
    
    // Clean-up ...
    free(done);

    return s1;
}

int main()
{
    char text[10] = "dobar dan", letters[6] = "abcde"; // NOTE: We need space for the NUL-terminator
    swapLetters(text, letters);
    printf("After transformation text is: '%s'\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

Note also, that I have increased the sizes of your `text` and `letters` arrays (in `main`) to allow for the **required** `nul`-terminator in those strings. You could also just declare those arrays with empty square brackets (i.e. `char text[] = ...`) so that the compiler allocates the size automatically.